# jQuery Run AJAX only every x seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a text input that uses ajax to get search results from the PHP script. Basically, at the moment the script sends each letter 1 by 1 to the PHP, which has to query the results from the database on each letter.

Instead, I would like it to be like if you type "Word" in 1 second, it just searches for entire "Word" instead of doing several searches for "W", "Wo", "Wor", "Word".

I tried to use window.SetTimetout for it, but that just makes it the search run 2 seconds late, but the letters are still sent 1 by 1.

```
$("#search").keyup(function(e) {
    var keyword = $("#search").val();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetItemList.php?search="+keyword,
            success: function(result) {
                $(".left").html(result);
            }
        });
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: @chsh But what can I do to capture the content of #search every 1 second and then send it to the PHP?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Clear Timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

```
var lastTimeout = null;
$("#search").keyup(function(e) {
    var keyword = $("#search").val();
    if (lastTimeout)
        clearTimeout(lastTimeout)
    lastTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetItemList.php?search="+keyword,
            success: function(result) {
                $(".left").html(result);
            }
        });
    },2000);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I'll mark it as asnwer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if there is already a timeout active before you create a new one.  Something like this:

```
var myTimeout = null;

$("#search").keyup(function(e) {
    var keyword = $("#search").val();

    if(myTimeout != null) {
        myTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "GetItemList.php?search="+keyword,
            success: function(result) {
                $(".left").html(result);
            myTimeout = null;
            }
        });
        },2000);
    }
});
```

This way, if you were to keep typing continuously for 10 seconds, you would end up with 4 or 5 requests total, one every 2 seconds or so.